# JSON members order in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: json, flash, actionscript, stringify

I'm using built-in functionality to create JSON string in Flash app.

Here example of my source code

```
objStr = JSON.stringify( 
        {
            version:"1.0",
            skin:"white",
            palette:{dataColor:"#0397d6",negativeDataColor:"#d40000",toolbarColor:"#056393"}
        });
```

I have a problem. Every time I've started my app (not executing createJSON function), I have different member order in JSON string as result.
For example:

```
{"version":"1.0","palette":{"negativeDataColor":"#d40000","dataColor":"#0397d6","toolbarColor":"#056393"},"skin":"white"}
```

or

```
{"palette":{"negativeDataColor":"#d40000","toolbarColor":"#056393","dataColor":"#0397d6"},"version":"1.0","skin":"white"}
```

How can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON objects are unordered, see [JSON.org](http://json.org/):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> 1. A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>      realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>      list, or associative array. An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs
> 2. An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an
>      array, vector, list, or sequence. An array is an **ordered** collection of values.

Order really doesn't matter since you should be retrieving the values by the key rather than iterating over them.

Comment: So, you mean it's doesn't matter in what order I'll get elements in JSON string? It will be correct for processed by service?

Comment: I think if the order matters you / the services are doing something wrong ;).

Comment: Sometimes it is convenient to have deterministic results, like when running a diff using standard diff tools. It'd be nice if you could tell it to order things in some way, even if the spec doesn't require it.

Comment: Creating a hash signature is a problem with how Flash handles native json. If you add a property to an object after creation, it seems to randomly choose the order.